# How to send files to a Parse server using Parse REST API and Retrofit?

Tags: android, parse-platform, retrofit2

I have built a Retrofit builder so that I can send files to a Parse database using Retrofit

```
public static Retrofit buildParseUpload() {
        Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl({contains server running Parse})
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(authenticate());
        return retrofitBuilder.build();
}
```

This is `authenticate()`:

```
private static OkHttpClient authenticateParse() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder()
                        .header("X-Parse-Application-Id", APPLICATION_ID)
                        .header("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", MASTER_KEY)
                        .method(request.method(), request.body());
                Request newRequest = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        });
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        return client;
    }
```

This is `ParseService`:

```
public interface ParseService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("classes/" + Parameter.Classes.TABLE_NAME + "/")
    Call<Void> uploadFile(@PartMap Map<String, Object> map);
}
```

And this is the `Call` instance:

```
private void saveFileToParse(File answerFile) {
        //TODO: Save file manually Parse
        String filePath = "";
        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitBuilder.buildParseUpload();
        ParseService parseService = retrofit.create(ParseService.class);
        Call<Void> call = parseService.uploadFile(getPartMap(answerFile));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response: " + response.body().toString());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response: " + response.code());
                    Log.d(TAG, "response: " + response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getPartMap(File file) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("file", file);
        return map;
    }
```

Retrofit version: `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0`

Result: **HTTP 400: Bad Request**

Log:

```
  D/OkHttp: --> POST http://parse.ip.address.xx:port/parse/2.2.16/classes/classes_of_files/ http/1.1
  D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=2b7a3c4d-8e13-4baa-b99f-2148560eafef
  D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 308
  D/OkHttp: X-Parse-Application-Id: —————
  D/OkHttp: X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ———————
  D/OkHttp: --> END POST
  D/OkHttp: --> POST http://parse.ip.address.xx:port/parse/2.2.16/classes/classes_of_files/ http/1.1
  D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=220df264-d21b-4ddd-b0d4-df13e2b4193e
  D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 305
  D/OkHttp: X-Parse-Application-Id: ——————
  D/OkHttp: X-Parse-REST-API-Key: —————
  D/OkHttp: --> END POST
E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-1341404215>, App: com.android.vending, Service: androidsecure
                                       elc: Long live credential not available.
                                           at eld.a(SourceFile:3099)
                                           at ejq.a(SourceFile:397)
                                           at ejp.a(SourceFile:31369)
                                           at ejp.a(SourceFile:313)
                                           at fla.a(SourceFile:1201)
                                           at fkz.a(SourceFile:530)
                                           at fkz.a(SourceFile:196)
                                           at egp.a(SourceFile:284)
                                           at egp.a(SourceFile:204)
                                           at egu.a(SourceFile:1510)
                                           at egt.a(SourceFile:920)
                                           at egt.e(SourceFile:534)
                                           at egs.a(SourceFile:37)
                                           at ehv.getAuthToken(SourceFile:179)
                                           at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:214)
                                           at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113)
                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
01-27 04:21:03.983 8965-1170/? W/GLSActivity: ehh: BadAuthentication
                                                  at egu.a(SourceFile:1526)
                                                  at egt.a(SourceFile:920)
                                                  at egt.e(SourceFile:534)
                                                  at egs.a(SourceFile:37)
                                                  at ehv.getAuthToken(SourceFile:179)
                                                  at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:214)
                                                  at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113)
                                                  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
  D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request http://52.220.38.201:1337/parse/2.2.16/classes/survey_usage_files/ (185ms)
  D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: Express
  D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
  D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Parse-Master-Key, X-Parse-REST-API-Key, X-Parse-Javascript-Key, X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token, X-Requested-With, X-Parse-Revocable-Session, Content-Type
  D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 30
  D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 20 Jan 2017 09:22:36 GMT
  D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
  D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
  D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request http://parse.ip.address.xx:port/parse/2.2.16/classes/classes_of_files/ (183ms)
  D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: Express
  D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
  D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Parse-Master-Key, X-Parse-REST-API-Key, X-Parse-Javascript-Key, X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token, X-Requested-With, X-Parse-Revocable-Session, Content-Type
  D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 30
  D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 20 Jan 2017 09:22:36 GMT
  D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
  D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
```

**Why am I not using Parse Android SDK?**

We determined that we needed to use the Parse REST API for this problem instead of the Parse Android SDK, as we are having problems with the Parse Android SDK when it comes to uploading files, especially while using its callbacks.

Please also take note that the Base URL is not `api.parse.com`, but another remote server of ours which is running Parse.

Your answers are very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show ParseService interface?

Comment: Done, @bigdestroyer. It's between authenticate() and Call

Comment: I think you sould use /files path instead of /classes and add the content type header. http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#files-uploading-files

Comment: What version of Retrofit are you using?

Comment: @bigdestroyer but then the /files path specifies that I should append the file name after the endpoint. I tried appending the absolute file path of the image in Postman. No such luck. I can only create new file with that endpoint. I need to upload an existing file, esp. a photo or a video.